# Why does JavaScript's eval need parentheses to eval JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I've learned (the hard way) that I need to add parentheses around JSON data, like this:

```
stuff = eval('(' + data_from_the_wire + ')');
// where data_from_the_wire was, for example {"text": "hello"}
```

(In Firefox 3, at least).

What's the reason behind this? I hate writing code without understanding what´s behind the hood.

Comment: I see you are not a native English speaker but '(' and ')' are parentheses. It may help other people find your post if you correct this.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Putting the parentheses around `data_from_the_wire` is effectively equivalent to

```
stuff = eval('return ' + data_from_the_wire + ';');
```

If you were to eval without the parentheses, then the code would be evaluated, and if you did have any named functions inside it those would be defined, but not returned.

Take as an example the ability to call a function just as it han been created:

```
(function() { alert('whoot'); })()
```

Will call the function that has just been defined.  The following, however, does not work:

```
function() { alert('whoot'); }()
```

So we see that the parentheses effectively turn then code into an expression that returns, rather than just code to run.

Comment: The first part isn't exactly correct; eval interprets the string as top-level code, so return doesn't work.

The issue with functions is similar to original question, because it's an ambiguity between a function *statement* and a function *expression* (see karim79's answer).

Comment: I really think this answer is incomplete as to why JSON literal, when being as argument to `eval()`, must be enclosed in parenthesis. @karim79's answer is more clear on this: the JSON literal's `{...}` would be parsed as block but not object literal (which it should be).

Answer (score 66):

`eval` accepts a sequence of Javascript statements. The Javascript parser
interprets the ‘{’ token, occuring within a statement as the start of a block and not the start of an object literal.

When you enclose your literal into parentheses like this: `({ data_from_the_wire })`
you are switching the Javascript parser into expression parsing mode. The token ‘{’ inside an expression means the start of an object literal declaration and **not** a block, and thus Javascript accepts it as an object literal.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure of the reason but I parse JSON by using [the JSON class](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) from [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html). It's much safer than using eval.

Comment: Why the downvote?
It seems like a valid answer.
Using eval is unsafe.

Comment: He's not asking how to use eval properly for parsing JSON, he's asking why there is a need for parenthesis.

Comment: @TimČas I realise I wasn't answering the question directly but when someone points a gun at their foot and asks why they need to remove the safety, I first advise them that pointing a gun at your foot might not be a great idea.

Comment: Yes, but if I ask how airbags work, the proper answer is describing how they work, not saying that crashing a car is bad :)

Comment: This is usually the best answer. Unless you are dealing with a large amount of data from a safe source being sent to an old browser that displays error messages every 5,000,000 statements. When *that* happens replacing the nice safe `JSON.parse` with `eval("(" + response + ")")` is a necessity.

Comment: I too was trying to remove the safety with a gun pointed to my foot, wondering why cars have to have an airbag... I think this answer is worthy.
PS: To sustain an opinion we do not necessarily need to be serious. Both above comments made my day.

Answer (score 9):

In JavaScript, curly brackets are used to create block statements:

```
{
var foo = "bar";
var blah = "baz";
doSomething();
}
```

The above lines can be put inside a string and `eval`uated without problem. Now consider this:

```
{
"foo": "bar",
"blah": "baz"
}
```

The curly brackets cause the JavaScript engine to think it is a group expression, hence the syntax error around the `:` character. Quote from [MDN...JavaScript Guide...Object Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_literals):

> You should not use an object literal at the beginning of a statement.
>   This will lead to an error or not behave as you expect, because the {
>   will be interpreted as the beginning of a block.

The workaround of wrapping the object literal inside `()` works by telling the engine to treat its contents as an expression, not as a block statement. So this does not work:

```
({
var foo = "bar";
var blah = "baz";
doSomething(evil);
})
// parse error
```

But this does:

```
({
"foo": "bar",
"blah": "baz"
})
// returns object
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because without round braces JavaScript tries to interpret `{"text": ...` as [a label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide:Loop_Statements:label_Statement) and fails. Try it in console and you'll get "invalid label" error.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the value of `data_from_the_wire`, actually. In most cases your syntax is ok, but a line that begins with `{` is parsed as a label, and yours is invalid. If you surround it with parenthesis, it prevents the parser from misinterpreting your expression.

Just a parsing problem, really. With strings, numbers or functions, you wouldn't have that problem.

One solution is to always eval instructions and not expressions. You can write

```
eval('var stuff = {"text": "hello"}');
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know, and I am actually interested in the answer to this, but my guess is that without the parentheses the data in `data_from_the_wire` would be interpreted as a closure.  Maybe the parentheses force evaluation and so the associative array is 'returned'.

This is the kind of guessing that leads to downvotes though =).

**EDIT**

Douglas Crockford mentions a syntax ambiguity on his [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html) site but that didn't really help me.