# Angularjs dynamic ng-click binding?

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-click, dynamic-binding

I am reading a Json file and dynamically creating the elements using angular template.I wanted to bind the event to ng-click which is mentioned in the json file,but it throws exception.Kindly help.
Thanks in Advance.

```
 <button id="{{controls.id}}" ng-click='{{controls.onAction}}' title="{{controls.tooltipText}}"
                                        ng-mouseover="mouseOver(this)" ng-mouseout="mouseOut(this)" style="font-size: 70%;
                                        border: none; border-spacing: 1px;" class="button">
                                        <img src="{{controls.imageSrc}}" class="image{{tabBoxes.Type}}" id="Img1" />
                                        {{controls.label}}
                                    </button>
```

Comment: Better you paste code here..as we are not mind readers

Answer (score 0):

Create a $scope.onAction() function in the controller, and change ng-click as follows:

```
ng-click='onAction()'
```

---

**Update in response to comment:**

Since the functions are strings, use `eval()`, e.g.:

```
$scope.onAction = eval('(' + functionAsString + ')');
```

See this [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2760992/4022015) on how to use `eval()` in JS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But in my application every button has different onaction methods.the function is a string from json and i m trying to map as click function.how to do.

Comment: Thanks again the eval is not working for me.but i have found another way to do it.                                                       var act = new Function(e.onAction);
        act();