# Given a function in a string format how do i convert it back to a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, function, eval

Say I have a function in javascript

```
var fn = function () {
        return 6 + 5;
};
```

and then I do

```
fn.toString();
```

which returns

```
"function () { return 6 + 5; }"
```

how can I turn this back into a function and eventually call it later on. I've tried `eval` as other people have said but this does not seem to be working for me. Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a name to the function, then you can call it. This should work

```
var fn = function () {
    return 6 + 5;
};
var stringFunc = fn.toString();

eval("var newfn = " + stringFunc);
console.log(newfn())
```

you can also execute it passing the parameters like this

```
console.log(eval("("+stringFunc+")()"))
```

Answer (score 1):

@LeeDennis just call `fn();` instead of `fn.toString();` the variable "fn" is the function you just need to add the parenthesis.

I console logged the outputs so you can see them.

//CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var fn = function () {
        return 6 + 5;
};
console.log(fn()); //returns 11
console.log(fn.toString()); //returns "function () { return 6 + 5; }"
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use eval():

```
fnString = 'function () { return 6 + 5; }';
fn = eval('(' + fnString + ')');
alert(fn());
```

Check this out:

[JavaScript eval() "syntax error" on parsing a function string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760953/javascript-eval-syntax-error-on-parsing-a-function-string)