# How to create an object with a function from string:

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, serialization

I have this code stored as string:

```
{
  "func": function (field) {
    var date = getDate(field);
    return date != -1;
  },
  "somethingElse": "Message",
  "somethingElse2": "Message2"
}
```

Is there a way to convert it to an object? JSON.parse don't allow functions.

Comment: replace `},` with `}(),`

Answer (score 2):

As `Durendal` already said, you have to deliver your function as a string that can be handled by `JSON.parse`. After that you can call your function with `eval`:

```js
var string = '{"func":"function (field) {return field;}","somethingElse": "Message","somethingElse2":"Message2"}';

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(string);
var func = eval("("+jsonObject["func"]+")");

document.write(func("abc"));
```

You may also be interested in this question: [JavaScript eval() "syntax error" on parsing a function string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760953/javascript-eval-syntax-error-on-parsing-a-function-string)

Answer (score 1):

Your string shoud look like this :

```
var string = '{"func":"function (field) {var date = getDate(field);return date != -1;}","somethingElse": "Message","somethingElse2":"Message2"}';

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(string);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pc6hdk1y/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to even store the method like this you need to use **replacer** function

```
var text = JSON.stringify(a, function(k,v){
  return typeof v == "function" ? v.toString() : v;
})
```

Now, to get the function back, you need to use the reviver function

```
JSON.parse(text,function(k,v){
  console.log(v);

  return typeof v == "string" && v.indexOf("function") == 0 ? new Function(v.substring(v.indexOf("{")+1, v.lastIndexOf("}"))) : v;
})
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `JSON` does not handle functions like this out of the box?

Comment: @Fidel90 I don't think it is secure to parse an arbitrary string into executable method. Secondly, JSON doesn't know if the value is a method or not, since all it gets is a string.

Comment: sadly seems the function arguments are not being restored on the parse

Comment: @Ralstlin wait, let me do something about that as well.

Comment: @Ralstlin it seems to me that unless function is using `arguments` object inside the function, it won't be able to use the variable arguments without `eval`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the function you probably need to do it like

```js
var data = {
                      "func": ["field", "var date = getDate(field); return date != -1;"],
             "somethingElse": "Message",
            "somethingElse2": "Message2"
           },
   jData = JSON.stringify(data),
   pData = JSON.parse(jData),
    func = new Function(pData.func[0],pData.func[1]);
document.write("<pre>" + func + "</pre>");
```