# I cannot understand the parentheses in this JavaScript statement

Tags: javascript, parentheses

I cannot understand the parentheses in JavaScript statement below:

```
({go_go: 'go'});
```

What does the `()` here mean?

I know `()` in function means this function is anonymous. Just like codes below. Is it right?

```
(function () {
    alert('something');
})();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that literal example, they have no purpose, but generally they're for enclosing an expression — specifically, for ensuring that the contents of the parens are read as an expression, not as a statement.

You'll see things like that when people are using `eval` to deserialize data in JSON format. So for instance, they might receive a string in the form:

```
var s = '{"go_go": "go"}';
```

...and use this to deserialize it:

```
var o = eval('(' + s + ')');
```

This is an old work-around to certain issues, but you're *much* better off using a proper JSON parsing library, such as any of the three listed on [Crockford's github page](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/). (Crockford being the inventor of JSON.) There's one there which does some regexes to detect various malformed-JSON stuff and then uses `eval`, and two others that don't use `eval` at all. (I would never use `eval` when dealing with JSON from an untrusted source.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You comment is helpful. And I also checked out the syntax diagram of expression statement. Now I've got the answer. =)

Answer (score 1):

I think [Why does JavaScript's eval need parentheses to eval JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964397/why-does-javascripts-eval-need-parentheses-to-eval-json-data) answers your question.

You don't need them if you just have a plain object literal in your code though.

In your function expression the outer `()` do not make the function anonymous (it already is as it has no name). However, to execute an anonymous function immediately after defining it they are necessary since `function(){}();` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Some people are in the habit of surrounding JSON objects with parenthesis...

```
var jsonObject = ({go_go: 'go'});
```

Is the same as

```
var jsonObject = {go_go: 'go'};
```

The reason they do this is because if you are retrieving JSON objects via an AJAX call, you often need the parenthesis to prevent a common parse error.

The following line of code often causes an invalid label error:

```
var jsonObject =  eval(stringOfJson);
```

And this is usually solved as follows:

```
var jsonObject =  eval( "(" + stringOfJson + ")" );
```

And finally, the practice of wrapping an immediate function in parenthesis should look like this...

```
(function () {
    alert('something');
}());
```

And the only reason you use the parenthesis is that it makes the immediate function more obvious (as recommened by www.jslint.com amongst others!)