# json text needs to wrap in parenthesis. why?

Tags: javascript, json

if you look at http://www.json.org/js.html
you will find a line that states:

> The text must be wrapped in parens to
>   avoid tripping on an ambiguity in
>   JavaScript's syntax.
>
> var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext +
>   ')');

can some body explain what this ambiguity is ???

Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does JavaScript's eval need parentheses to eval JSON data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964397/why-does-javascripts-eval-need-parentheses-to-eval-json-data)

Comment: It seems that this is a duplicate question. Try going to this link to see why it is so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964397/why-does-javascripts-eval-need-parentheses-to-eval-json-data

Comment: I think you are right it's a duplicate. that link answers my question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: http://rayfd.wordpress.com/2007/03/28/why-wont-eval-eval-my-json-or-json-object-object-literal/

"Note that an ExpressionStatement cannot start with an opening curly brace because that might make it ambiguous with a Block"