# When creating .on() elements in a for loop, how can I make the .on(function) call the current index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I hope the title makes sense.

I am using a `for` loop to create one or more `$(document).on()` elements. Inside each `$(document).on()` element created, I need it to call a function `foo(currentIndex)` where the `currentIndex` is the value of the index at the time of the `.on()` definition.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xLbses7w/

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
var event = ['click', 'click'];
var element = ['#someId', '#someId2'];

for (i = 0; i < event.length; i++)
{
    $(document).on(event[i], element[i], function ()
    {
        foo(i);    // would like this to be the value of i when the function was created
    });
}


function foo(arg)
{
    alert(arg);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="someId">div1</div> <br/>
<div id="someId2">div2</div>
```

**The problem:** When I click on the element using the `.on()` function I have created, it uses the latest value of `i` (which in this case is 2).

**Desired Behavior:** When I click on div1, it should alert `0`, and when I click on div2 it should alert `1` (the current indexes at the time of `.on()` definition.)

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069614/javascript-puzzle-scope/9069680#9069680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a closure:

```
for (i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        $(document).on(event[i], element[i], function () {
            foo(i); // would like this to be the value of i when the function was created
        });
    })(i);
}
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: whoever downvoted this, tell community why? +1

Comment: thanks. Simple, easy to read solution that doesn't modify the HTML

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.data()` to store the index value

```
$(element[i]).data('index', i);
$(document).on(event[i], element[i], function () {
    foo($(this).data('index')); 
});
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/7xe2v54y/)