# Unterminated Regular Expression Literal Error

Tags: javascript, xml, jsp

I encountered a Javascript error while parsing an XML file. My code looks like this:

```
var det = eval( "(" +  xmlhttp.responseText + ")");
```

the returned xml file for this code would be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><accountss><accounts>`<password>1234</password><userid>arjel</userid></accounts></accountss>
```

I have an unterminated regular expression literal error when executing this code. What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to parse XML using an old, slow, dangerous piece of code designed to parse **JSON** by evaluating it as JavaScript. Unlike JSON, XML is not a subset of JavaScript, so it errors when you try to do this.

Just access `xmlhttp.responseXML` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need eval(). Eval will try to "execute" your xml concatenated with 2 brackets as javascript but for obvious reasons it will fail (not javascript code - can't execute it).

If you just want to concatenate your XML with round brackets do it without eval():

```
var det = "(" +  xmlhttp.responseText + ")";
```

Comment: See [Why does JavaScript's eval need parentheses to eval JSON data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964397/why-does-javascripts-eval-need-parentheses-to-eval-json-data) for details of the pattern used in the question. It seems very unlikely that the goal is to get a string of XML surrounding with parentheses.