# Evil eval + parenthesis sample?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have read many question here in the site but didnt got to understand the problem with the parenthesis thing.

```
eval( '{a:alert(1)}'); //alert 1
```

but also this alert 1 :

```
eval( '('+'{a:alert(1)}'+')'); //alert 1
```

So how does `'()'` helps me ?

I already know that `()` makes the code to be read as epxression and not as a statement

but I dont see in my sample how it is gonna help.

Can you please provide a sample ?

Comment: You answered the question yourself already: Parentheses are used to interpret something as object literals (within an expression) rather than a code block.

Comment: @RobW if it is the same , why would i need `()` ?  I dont see the benefit.( and i must be wrong). can you please provide an example which will do harm to my site , and how () will help?

Comment: It depends on what you want. What is your intention? `{a:alert(1)}` is a code block with label a, `({a:alert(0)})` is an object literal with key a containing the result of `alert(0)`.

Comment: @RobW I want to see an example which will do harm to my site , and see how `()` helps solving it.

Comment: There is none, `()` is not going to make your code any safer. If you're using `'(' + user_input + ')'`, then you're being doomed already. Furthermore, if you're using `'(' + input_from_url + ')'`, then you can say goodbye to your website's client-side security. The attacker can use `(function(){/*code*/}())`, which works fine whetehr you're using parentheses or not.

Comment: @RobW ok... so using or not using `()` is the same thing  ?

Comment: With regards to making code more secure against user input, yes.

Comment: @RobW Sorry to keep asking ....so why all these posts about using eval with `()` ?

Comment: See my third comment on your question. Many abuse `eval` to parse JSON. The ones who parse JSON want to get the object literal containing the serialized information, so they want to avoid that the input is parsed as a code block, by adding parentheses. (The correct way to parse JSON is [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), by the way).

Comment: @RobW so this is what i was asking. parsing json without  `()` can be bad. can you please supply a sample ? what kind of json sample can be harmful ?

Comment: You've given the example yourself already, and I explained the difference between those examples in my third comment. There's not much left to explain. If you want to know more, look on Stack Overflow for existing answers on this (popular) topic. For instance: [Why does JavaScript's eval need parentheses to eval JSON data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964397/why-does-javascripts-eval-need-parentheses-to-eval-json-data)

Comment: @RobW No I didnt supply an example which can do harm to my site. since both of my sample executes. I already read the linked answer. but noone talked about json sample which can do harm.

Comment: JSON by [definition](http://json.org/) describes the format of how an object with numbers, strings, arrays, booleans, `null` and other plain objects have to be encoded. So, you won't be able to find a "JSON sample which can do harm". In [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900060/evil-eval-parenthesis-sample#comment19153273_13900060) I gave an example of the risk of parsing non-JSON using eval instead of `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
eval("({a: 'my great object'}.a);");
```

and

```
eval("{a: 'my great object'}.a;");
```

As already mentioned: the second one is a block of code with label so .a simply doesn't have any sense.

Comment: neo ,IMHO , the `()` is only for json...right ? but `{a:'...'}` is not json...Im jsut having a problem to understand why should I use () when eval json obj.

Comment: Use JSON.parse instead. (search for famous: eval is evil). It's not only with json: see `function a(){
 return (endl here!)
 {a: 'a'};
}
a();` does not work as expected (semicolon insertion + named block of code here)