# Using eval with `with`

Tags: javascript

I know `eval` and `with` are usually discouraged, but putting that aside for the moment, I'm having trouble getting this code to work:

```
with({ a: 'hello world' }){
    var output = eval('{ text: a }')
}
```

I was expecting `output` to be the **object**:

```
{ text: "hello world" }
```

but instead `output` is the **string**  'hello world'

Can someone help me see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parentheses around it:

```
 var output = eval('({ text: a })')
```

see e.g. [Why does JavaScript's eval need parentheses to eval JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964397/why-does-javascripts-eval-need-parentheses-to-eval-json-data)