# javascript - Why add parenthesis when evaling objects?

Tags: javascript

Content of response: `{"body": "123", "timestamp": 1366853254, "html": "<div class=\"message\" id=\"m721cfd57-cf57-4fa9-b0a4-263151da4f7d\"><b>Scuk: <\/b>123<\/div>\n", "from": "Scuk", "id": "721cfd57-cf57-4fa9-b0a4-263151da4f7d"}`

Code:

```
console.log( eval( '(' + response + ')'));
console.log( eval( response ));
```

No error reported at `console.log( eval( '(' + response + ')'));` while `unexpected token` reported at `console.log( eval( response ));`. Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964397/why-does-javascripts-eval-need-parentheses-to-eval-json-data

Comment: `console.log( eval ( response + ));` has the "`+`" in there, which is invalid. The rest of the reasoning is below

Comment: @pickypg Sorry, that's a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We add parenthesis so it will be evaluated as an expression. For example, `({})` is interpreted as an object literal while `{ ... }` is parsed as a block statement.

```
{
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2
}

// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```