# Using eval to evaluate JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I was looking at someone's code and saw the following.

Assuming JSON is just a regular JSON file, what does following do?

```
var obj = eval("["+json+"]");
```

I guess I really don't understand what `["+json+"]` is doing? Is this just wrapping what's in JSON in `""`?

Comment: Don't use `eval` to obtain JSON from strings, `JSON.parse()` is safer and preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json is a subset of javascript. So eval will just turn the json into a js-object (except when the json describes an object, then you [need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964397/why-does-javascripts-eval-need-parentheses-to-eval-json-data) to wrap it in '(' ')'). Wrapping it in [ ] will put the object in an array.

However, if the json source is not from a trusted source, the json could also contain arbitrary code, therefore eval should not be used for this purpose. **Use JSON.parse instead, it is much safer an easier to use**

```
var json = JSON.stringify(object);
var array = eval("[" + json + "]"); //array contains one element which is a copy of object. Because json is valid javascript.
```

Comment: great but what's the difference between eval([json]) and eval("[" + json + "]"); ??

Comment: This is like asking what's the difference between sticking my hand in a boiling pot of water instead of merely sticking my hand on the stove burner after the boiling pot of water has been removed.

Comment: eval([json]) is not even a valid eval call. eval evaluates the given string as javascript code. With eval([json]) you are passing an array instead of a string, which is undefined.