# Parse function inside Json

Tags: javascript, json, function

I have this JSON as a result of the function JSON.stringify():

```
{"get":"function (f,g){'use strict';var h,i;if(i={},'string'==typeof f){if('object'==typeof g)for(h in g)i[h]=g[h];i.url=f}else if('object'==typeof f)for(h in f)i[h]=f[h];return i.type=i.type||d,i.oauthio={provider:a,tokens:b,request:c},e.http(i)}","post":"function (f,g){'use strict';var h,i;if(i={},'string'==typeof f){if('object'==typeof g)for(h in g)i[h]=g[h];i.url=f}else if('object'==typeof f)for(h in f)i[h]=f[h];return i.type=i.type||d,i.oauthio={provider:a,tokens:b,request:c},e.http(i)}"}
```

How you can see there are functions inside values. I want to rebuild this JavaScript object, my goal is to remove the quotes  in the risult but also the values; because functions, in this case, are recognized as string. I want something like this:`{key : value}`

Now I get:`{key : "value"}`

Comment: With `eval` or `Function` (after some preprocessing). You can automate this by passing a reviver function to `JSON.parse`, just as explained in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). I strongly advice against storing functions as data though.

Comment: I've tried both, but nothing . `eval` doesn't work because the values ​​missing the function name.

Comment: `eval('(' + str + ')')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**QUICK ANSWER:**

The function bellow will do it:

```
function fix(obj){

    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            obj[property] = eval("(" + obj[property] + ")");
        }
    }

}
```

If ***obj*** has your JSON parsed object then just do the following:

```
fix(obj);
console.log(obj); // in case you want to see the change in the console
```

**EXPLANATION (IF YOU NEED ONE):**

You will be able to get the javascript function expression if you enclose the string with parentheses '()' before invoking eval.

So the steps to achieve the desired result are:

1. Enclose the function expression string in parentheses (see footnotes for the reason why)
2. Invoke the eval function to evaluate the function declaration expression
3. Assign the function declaration expression to the same property that contained the string value

For the simplistic example you gave, you can get the desired results by:

```
var obj = {"get":"function (f,g){'use strict';var h,i;if(i={},'string'==typeof f){if('object'==typeof g)for(h in g)i[h]=g

[h];i.url=f}else if('object'==typeof f)for(h in f)i[h]=f[h];return i.type=i.type||d,i.oauthio=

{provider:a,tokens:b,request:c},e.http(i)}","post":"function (f,g){'use strict';var h,i;if(i={},'string'==typeof f){if

('object'==typeof g)for(h in g)i[h]=g[h];i.url=f}else if('object'==typeof f)for(h in f)i[h]=f[h];return i.type=i.type||

d,i.oauthio={provider:a,tokens:b,request:c},e.http(i)}"};

obj.get = eval("(" + obj.get + ")");
obj.post = eval("(" + obj.post + ")");
```

You can automate that by using the following function:

```
function fix(obj){

    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            obj[property] = eval("(" + obj[property] + ")");
        }
    }

}
```

Your final code should be something like:

```
function fix(obj){

        for (var property in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                obj[property] = eval("(" + obj[property] + ")");
            }
        }

    }


var obj = {"get":"function (f,g){'use strict';var h,i;if(i={},'string'==typeof f){if('object'==typeof g)for(h in g)i[h]=g

    [h];i.url=f}else if('object'==typeof f)for(h in f)i[h]=f[h];return i.type=i.type||d,i.oauthio=

    {provider:a,tokens:b,request:c},e.http(i)}","post":"function (f,g){'use strict';var h,i;if(i={},'string'==typeof f){if

    ('object'==typeof g)for(h in g)i[h]=g[h];i.url=f}else if('object'==typeof f)for(h in f)i[h]=f[h];return i.type=i.type||

    d,i.oauthio={provider:a,tokens:b,request:c},e.http(i)}"};

fix(obj);
```

---

Footnotes:

In case you have interest to know why the parentheses are needed please check the link below:

[Why does JavaScript's eval need parentheses to eval JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964397/why-does-javascripts-eval-need-parentheses-to-eval-json-data)

Comment: With your code I get this result: `{get: function (), post: function()}` Where am I wrong?

Comment: I focused on the functions , the code doesn't work because the function contains undefined variables that actually are defined outside the function , solutions?

Comment: It works at least with the example you provided, if you have other cases that don't work, please post them here so I can try to help you.

Comment: Declaring a variable obj as you wrote, this code for me doesn't work: 
`for(var property in obj){
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(property)){
              obj[property] = eval("("+obj[property]+")");
            }
          }
``console.log(obj);`
The risult is: `{ get: function (), post: function () }`, try it.

Comment: The function statement is interpreted correctly and assigned to the variables as expected. Now if your function does not contain valid code, then for sure you will get an error if you try to execute it, in your case there are undefined variable being used. Fix the function and it will work. See this simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/d2bakop8/

Comment: This is my output on Chrome Console : Object get: function (f,g){'use strict';var h,i;if(i={},'string'==typeof f){if('object'==typeof g)for(h in g)i[h]=g[h];i.url=f}else if('object'==typeof f)for(h in f)i[h]=f[h];return i.type=i.type||d,i.oauthio={provider:a,tokens:b,request:c},e.http(i)}post: function (f,g){'use strict';var h,i;if(i={},'string'==typeof f){if('object'==typeof g)for(h in g)i[h]=g[h];i.url=f}else if('object'==typeof f)for(h in f)i[h]=f[h];return i.type=i.type||d,i.oauthio={provider:a,tokens:b,request:c},e.http(i)}

Comment: Where are you executing this?

Comment: This however is my result [https://jsfiddle.net/d2bakop8/1/]. 
I'll check the function, it worked before I used stringify and your function. The function corresponds perfectly so I don't understand why it doesn't work. I will investigate.

Comment: The jsfiddle firebug output wont show the function definition but the function is there... if you define a regular function like var a = function(b){return b;}; console.log(a); wont show it either... if you do the exact same thing on Chrome or Firefox you will see the function correctly defined, give it a shot in the browser.. <html><script>insert code here and open the page</script></html>

Comment: There are two separate things that need to be understood. One is the code needed to interpret the string as a function expression and assign to a variable. This is what the code does... the other thing is being able to execute the function after that. If the interpreted function contains errors then it wont run, as in any other javascript code. Try to use that function that you have as string as if it was declared normally and see what happens... you will see that you cannot execute it because some of the used variable are not declared inside the function.

Comment: I run it in Firefox but I have exactly the same result as jsfiddle . I see: `{get: function(),post: function()}` on the console and if I click on "function()" Firefox shows me an empty function. The same json before performing these operations was displayed properly. Now I try..

Comment: The function is there, Firefox wont show the content , but the function is there if you try to execute it will work... if you do the same thing on Chrome you will see the function content, but that's just how the console.log works in both browsers, one shows the content the other doesnt.

Comment: Exactly! If you see is what I wrote in the second comment ... I tried to use the function as if it was declared normally and it works properly, using the variables defined outside the function . Are you telling me that I can't use `eval` for this reason ?

Comment: The function is recognized , but the variable declared outside no. That's the problem.

Comment: That's just how scope chain works in Javascript, because you are assigning the function to an object the external variables will not be visible... if you declare the function in a place where the variables are visible then it will work...

Comment: if you want to fix the variable definitions (this is outside the scope of this question) , use the function below:  function fix(obj){
    
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    
     obj[property] = obj[property].replace('function', 'function internal');
     obj[property] = "function (f,g){ var a = this.a; var d = this.d; var b = this.b; var c = this.c; var e = this.e; " + obj[property];
     obj[property] = obj[property] + " internal(f,g);}";
            obj[property] = eval("(" + obj[property] + ")");
        }
    }
    
    }

Comment: and execute the function using apply like this: fix(obj);

var scope = {a: '123', d:'abc', b: 'aaa', c:'ddd', e:{http : function(){}}};

obj.get.apply(scope,['param1','param2']);

Comment: in the example I assigned dummy values to the scope properties, but they should have the respective values used inside the function... when you call apply, the array [param1, param2] should have the parameters that you are passing to the get or post function

Answer (score 4):

this solution is better than using `eval` :

let's say `obj` contains your json, which means the function is `obj.get` but it is a sting, to convert it to a real function, you can use the constructor `Function`

```
obj.get = new Function(obj.get);
```

Note that I tried it on your code but the string you have posted has some errors on it. make sure your function is correct.

Comment: You might want to explain why it is better. Also this won't just work with the OP's code. Some preprocessing has to be done.

Comment: Thanks for the help , if I wanted to put this code in a 'for' or  'while'?

Comment: do you mean your object will have many functions on it ? if so, is it going to have only function or other elements ?

Comment: I need automate that, if I had a long json file whose values ​​are all functions , I would first " transform" all in an object and then use it . Look at the other answer to get an idea of what I need. (Unfortunately that solution does not work for now).